# React Leaflet onClick outside

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get react-leaflet opening a popup react way.

1. when layer is clicked properties at state are updated to indicate current selected position
2. a popup is displayed with info
3. when i click outside elements (eg. polylines), popup is closed auto.

How can i detect this click outside (empty map area) in order to update the current selected element to null?

One option tried was associating onClick also to the map but then two events are associated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `closeOnClick` option to be set to `false`.
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#popup-closeonclick